How to check which context type is being used by a <canvas>? (2D, WebGL)
When you see a <canvas> element on a web page what is the super fast way to find if it's created using 2d or WebGL context?

Request the context again, only one type of context can be generated by every <canvas> element, using another type would return null:


const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl2");

const retrieveContext = (canvas) =>
  ["2d", "webgl", "webgl2", "webgpu", "bitmaprenderer"]
    .find(type => !!canvas.getContext(type));
  
console.log("retrieved", retrieveContext(canvas));




Note: If you need to support old websites, you might want to add "experimental-webgl" into the list, but then you'd have to wrap the call to getContext() in a try {} catch {} block since unrecognized types should throw, and Safari never recognized that non-standard type.

This code may break things since it will create a context for the canvas if it doesn't yet have one.

That's to be used on a page where the visitor wants to check how something on a canvas has been drawn, so it's indeed expected that something has been drawn on it and that a context has been requested already.
